# c# windows phone Downloads folder

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202959(v=vs.105).aspx
i create a backgroundtransfer. i want when download is completed, that file moves to "Downloads Folder on root directory" (Phone or SD Card/Downloads). i don't know how can i make it, microsoft changes all codes on Windows Phone.

microsoft wrote a code on that topic>

```
case TransferStatus.Completed:

  // If the status code of a completed transfer is 200 or 206, the
  // transfer was successful
  if (transfer.StatusCode == 200 || transfer.StatusCode == 206)
  {
    // Remove the transfer request in order to make room in the
    // queue for more transfers. Transfers are not automatically
    // removed by the system.
    RemoveTransferRequest(transfer.RequestId);

    // In this example, the downloaded file is moved into the root
    // Isolated Storage directory
    using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
      string filename = transfer.Tag;
      if (isoStore.FileExists(filename))
      {
        isoStore.DeleteFile(filename);
      }
      isoStore.MoveFile(transfer.DownloadLocation.OriginalString, filename);
    }
  }
break;
```

but i dont know where goes that file when moved!

please give me a code.

Comment: As far as i know, an application can only store data in the app storage. Basically you cannot access the SD card directly or store files in SD card. Files can only be stored in an app's safe storage. One app cannot access another app's storage or files

Comment: @kshitijgandhi That's not true. Even in WP8.0 you were able to access SD card after adding file associations. In WP8.1 it's far more easier by using [KnownFolders.RemovableDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.removabledevices).

Comment: thanks alot. but in WP8.0 haven't KnownFolders.RemovableDevices and in WP8.1 haven't BackgroundTransferService to download a file in background and i don't know how can i download a file in background in WP8.1. can you tell me about "file associations" you said?

Comment: What did you set in `transferRequest.DownloadLocation`?

Comment: i didn't wrote that code, microsoft did!